# Question put on hold as off-topic but maybe spam?

Tags: support, status-completed

[Can anyone provide me high PR rank guest posting sites for SEO activity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080272/can-anyone-provide-me-high-pr-rank-guest-posting-sites-for-seo-activity) has been put on hold but I feel it's a form of spam via the user profile.

I clearly remember a previous post by the same user but I can't find it in my list of flagged posts.

I've reported it as spam but also wanted to flag it for moderator attention but couldn't do so. Hence this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was already removed as spam.